# How to configure Newtonsoft serialization from Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

How do I configure the Newtonsoft serialization settings for an Azure Functions app on .NET 6 with in-process functions. In the Startup, I tried `Services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonOptions(...)` but that seems to be for System.Text.Json which has no effect on my response data. Apparently Functions use Newtonsoft by default. I tried `AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters()...` as some SO articles discussed but that seems to be for .NET 3.1 or something older. I don't have and can't find such an extension method. I also tried looking for the `AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension but didn't find that either despite having the same using statements as the example I saw that used it.

Clearly there are lots of old docs out there with the various versions of .NET Core. Can anyone tell me how to do it in the latest?

**Edit:** I'm also open to hearing how to configure the web host to use System.Text.Json for my response data as that would also satisfy my needs, but wouldn't directly answer this particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AddNewtonsoftJson()` extension which is made available by adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` as a dependency from NuGet.

You can add a startup to your function project as below

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Fucntions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.services.AddJsonOptions(options => 
    {
      options.SerializerSettings. //your Json settings
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can inject any other dependencies here as you would a normally do in dotnet core.

For NewtonSoft you would have the below

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Fucntions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
    {
      options.SerializerSettings. //your Json settings
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As my question stated -- `AddJsonOptions` is for the `System.Text.Json` library, not `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: Okay but that would be a similar approach, will update my answer

Comment: Ok, I had seen and mentioned in the question that I tried that already. However the extension didn't exist for me. I just did another search for the extension and see now I need to bring in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`. This was the missing detail for me. Thanks for the help